# What am I doing wrong with this Xpath Query?

Tags: xpath

I've been having a play with some Xpath queries but I just can't get this one.

Here's the current string: `"/html/body/div/div[8]/table/tr/td[2]/a"`

It's showing the information below, but I need to grab "Australia" or node 5. I've tried last() and selecting a node on the a but no luck.

Anyone able to help?

[image]

Comment: Some sample XML would help ... if it's being removed by SO then use the code `{}` tool in the editor.

Comment: I think we need to see the XML too (or XHTML or whatever)

Comment: The page i'm trying to read is: http://ip-lookup.net/index.php?203.36.66.252 I'm trying to pickup what the country of origin is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seem to work

```
/html/body/div/div[8]/table/tr[3]/td[2]/a
```

You seemed to be on the wrong row. But will the structure always be this static? Maybe you should try to look for something "better" in the page, such as the href containing "country" so be somewhat more resilient to structure changes.